# Where can I download the latest release of Ubuntu?

Tags: release-management

A new version of Ubuntu has been released. I still can't find it on ubuntu.com. Where can it be downloaded from, or is it the only way to install it using update-manager to upgrade an existing installation?

Comment: This is now the canonical question on where to download the latest version of Ubuntu.

Comment: @jrg Should this still be considered the canonical "where to get latest version" question? Two versions have been released since any of these answers were last updated. If the answer is yes, I'll go ahead and edit them (provided nobody else does so first).

Comment: @EliahKagan go right ahead.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can download it from any of the following:

- [Ubuntu Download](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/ubuntu/download) page,
- [releases.ubuntu.com](http://releases.ubuntu.com) ([precise](http://releases.ubuntu.com/precise/), [trusty](http://releases.ubuntu.com/trusty), [xenial](http://releases.ubuntu.com/xenial/))
- [Official CD Mirrors](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+cdmirrors)

Answer (score 9):

All Ubuntu releases can be found at the [releases](http://releases.ubuntu.com/releases/) and/or [old releases](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/) pages respectively.
┏━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┯━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┯━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┯━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┓
┃       Version of Ubuntu (Desktop)      │     Directly    │      Torrent      │     Metalink     ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃           Ubuntu 14.04 LTS          │   [32-bit](http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04/ubuntu-14.04-desktop-i386.iso) or [64-bit](http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04/ubuntu-14.04-desktop-amd64.iso)  │   [32-bit](http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04/ubuntu-14.04-desktop-i386.iso.torrent) or [64-bit](http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04/ubuntu-14.04-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent)  │   [32-bit](http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04/ubuntu-14.04-desktop-i386.manifest) or [64-bit](http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04/ubuntu-14.04-desktop-amd64.metalink)  ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃       Ubuntu 13.10       │   [32-bit](http://releases.ubuntu.com/13.10/ubuntu-13.10-desktop-i386.iso) or [64-bit](http://releases.ubuntu.com/13.10/ubuntu-13.10-desktop-amd64.iso)  │   [32-bit](http://releases.ubuntu.com/13.10/ubuntu-13.10-desktop-i386.iso.torrent) or [64-bit](http://releases.ubuntu.com/13.10/ubuntu-13.10-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent)  │   [32-bit](http://releases.ubuntu.com/13.10/ubuntu-13.10-desktop-i386.metalink) or [64-bit](http://releases.ubuntu.com/13.10/ubuntu-13.10-desktop-amd64.metalink)  ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃       Ubuntu 13.04       │   [32-bit](http://releases.ubuntu.com/13.04/ubuntu-13.04-desktop-i386.iso) or [64-bit](http://releases.ubuntu.com/13.04/ubuntu-13.04-desktop-amd64.iso)  │   [32-bit](http://releases.ubuntu.com/13.04/ubuntu-13.04-desktop-i386.iso.torrent) or [64-bit](http://releases.ubuntu.com/13.04/ubuntu-13.04-desktop-i386.iso.torrent)  │   [32-bit](http://releases.ubuntu.com/13.04/ubuntu-13.04-desktop-i386.metalink) or [64-bit](http://releases.ubuntu.com/13.04/ubuntu-13.04-desktop-amd64.metalink)  ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃       Ubuntu 12.10       │   [32-bit](http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.10/ubuntu-12.10-desktop-i386.iso) or [64-bit](http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.10/ubuntu-12.10-desktop-amd64.iso)  │   [32-bit](http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.10/ubuntu-12.10-desktop-i386.iso.torrent) or [64-bit](http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.10/ubuntu-12.10-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent)  │   [32-bit](http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.10/ubuntu-12.10-desktop-i386.metalink) or [64-bit](http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.10/ubuntu-12.10-desktop-amd64.metalink)  ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃           Ubuntu 12.04 LTS          │   [32-bit](http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.04/ubuntu-12.04.4-desktop-i386.iso) or [64-bit](http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.04/ubuntu-12.04.4-desktop-amd64.iso)  │   [32-bit](http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.04/ubuntu-12.04.4-desktop-i386.iso.torrent) or [64-bit](http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.04/ubuntu-12.04.4-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent)  │   [32-bit](http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.04/ubuntu-12.04.4-desktop-i386.metalink) or [64-bit](http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.04/ubuntu-12.04.4-desktop-amd64.metalink)  ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃       Ubuntu 11.10       │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/oneiric/ubuntu-11.10-desktop-i386.iso) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/oneiric/ubuntu-11.10-alternate-amd64.iso)  │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/oneiric/ubuntu-11.10-desktop-i386.iso.torrent) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/oneiric/ubuntu-11.10-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent)  │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/oneiric/ubuntu-11.10-desktop-i386.metalink) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/oneiric/ubuntu-11.10-desktop-amd64.metalink)  ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃       Ubuntu 11.04       │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/11.04/ubuntu-11.04-desktop-i386.iso) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/11.04/ubuntu-11.04-desktop-amd64.iso)  │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/11.04/ubuntu-11.04-desktop-i386.iso.torrent) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/11.04/ubuntu-11.04-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent)  │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/11.04/ubuntu-11.04-desktop-i386.metalink) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/11.04/ubuntu-11.04-desktop-amd64.metalink)  ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃       Ubuntu 10.10       │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/10.10/ubuntu-10.10-desktop-i386.iso) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/10.10/ubuntu-10.10-desktop-amd64.iso)  │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/10.10/ubuntu-10.10-desktop-i386.iso.torrent) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/10.10/ubuntu-10.10-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent)  │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/10.10/ubuntu-10.10-desktop-i386.metalink) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/10.10/ubuntu-10.10-desktop-amd64.metalink)  ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃           Ubuntu 10.04 LTS          │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/lucid/ubuntu-10.04.4-desktop-i386.iso) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/lucid/ubuntu-10.04.4-desktop-amd64.iso)  │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/lucid/ubuntu-10.04.4-desktop-i386.iso.torrent) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/lucid/ubuntu-10.04.4-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent)  │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/lucid/ubuntu-10.04.4-desktop-amd64.metalink) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/lucid/ubuntu-10.04.4-alternate-amd64.metalink)  ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃         Ubuntu 9.10         │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/karmic/ubuntu-9.10-desktop-i386.iso) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/karmic/ubuntu-9.10-desktop-amd64.iso)  │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/karmic/ubuntu-9.10-desktop-i386.iso.torrent) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/karmic/ubuntu-9.10-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent)  │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/karmic/ubuntu-9.10-desktop-amd64.metalink) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/karmic/ubuntu-9.10-desktop-i386.metalink)  ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃         Ubuntu 9.04         │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/jaunty/ubuntu-9.04-desktop-i386.iso) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/jaunty/ubuntu-9.04-desktop-amd64.iso)  │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/jaunty/ubuntu-9.04-desktop-i386.iso.torrent) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/jaunty/ubuntu-9.04-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent)  │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/jaunty/ubuntu-9.04-desktop-i386.metalink) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/jaunty/ubuntu-9.04-desktop-amd64.metalink)  ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃         Ubuntu 8.10         │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/intrepid/ubuntu-8.10-desktop-i386.iso) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/intrepid/ubuntu-8.10-desktop-amd64.iso)  │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/intrepid/ubuntu-8.10-desktop-i386.iso.torrent) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/intrepid/ubuntu-8.10-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent)  │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/intrepid/ubuntu-8.10-desktop-i386.metalink) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/intrepid/ubuntu-8.10-desktop-amd64.metalink)  ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃        Ubuntu 8.04 LTS       │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/hardy/ubuntu-8.04.4-desktop-i386.iso) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/hardy/ubuntu-8.04.4-desktop-amd64.iso)  │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/hardy/ubuntu-8.04.4-desktop-i386.iso.torrent) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/hardy/ubuntu-8.04.4-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent)  │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/hardy/ubuntu-8.04.4-desktop-i386.metalink) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/hardy/ubuntu-8.04.4-desktop-amd64.metalink)  ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃         Ubuntu 7.10         │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/gutsy/ubuntu-7.10-desktop-i386.iso) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/gutsy/ubuntu-7.10-desktop-amd64.iso)  │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/gutsy/ubuntu-7.10-desktop-i386.iso.torrent) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/gutsy/ubuntu-7.10-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent)  │    Not  Available    ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃         Ubuntu 7.04         │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/feisty/ubuntu-7.04-desktop-i386.iso) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/feisty/ubuntu-7.04-desktop-amd64.iso)  │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/feisty/ubuntu-7.04-desktop-i386.iso.torrent) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/feisty/ubuntu-7.04-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent)  │    Not  Available    ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃         Ubuntu 6.10         │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/edgy/ubuntu-6.10-desktop-i386.iso) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/edgy/ubuntu-6.10-desktop-amd64.iso)  │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/edgy/ubuntu-6.10-desktop-i386.iso.torrent) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/edgy/ubuntu-6.10-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent)  │    Not  Available    ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃        Ubuntu 6.06 LTS       │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/dapper/ubuntu-6.06.1-desktop-i386.iso) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/dapper/ubuntu-6.06.1-desktop-amd64.iso)  │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/dapper/ubuntu-6.06.1-desktop-i386.iso.torrent) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/dapper/ubuntu-6.06.1-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent)  │    Not  Available    ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃          Ubuntu 5.10 DVD          │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/breezy/ubuntu-5.10-dvd-i386.iso) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/breezy/ubuntu-5.10-dvd-amd64.iso)  │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/breezy/ubuntu-5.10-dvd-i386.iso.torrent) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/breezy/ubuntu-5.10-dvd-amd64.iso.torrent)  │    Not  Available    ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃        Ubuntu 5.10 Install        │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/breezy/ubuntu-5.10-install-i386.iso) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/breezy/ubuntu-5.10-install-amd64.iso)  │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/breezy/ubuntu-5.10-install-i386.iso.torrent) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/breezy/ubuntu-5.10-install-amd64.iso.torrent)  │    Not  Available    ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃       Ubuntu 5.10 Live      │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/breezy/ubuntu-5.10-live-i386.iso) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/breezy/ubuntu-5.10-live-amd64.iso)  │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/breezy/ubuntu-5.10-live-i386.iso.torrent) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/breezy/ubuntu-5.10-live-amd64.iso.torrent)  │    Not  Available    ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃          Ubuntu 5.04 DVD          │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/hoary/ubuntu-5.04-dvd-i386.iso) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/hoary/ubuntu-5.04-dvd-amd64.iso)  │    Not  Available    │    Not  Available    ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃        Ubuntu 5.04 Install        │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/hoary/ubuntu-5.04-install-i386.iso) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/hoary/ubuntu-5.04-install-amd64.iso)  │    Not  Available    │    Not  Available    ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃       Ubuntu 5.04 Live      │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/hoary/ubuntu-5.04-live-i386.iso) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/hoary/ubuntu-5.04-live-amd64.iso)  │    Not  Available    │    Not  Available    ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃        Ubuntu 4.10 Install        │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/warty/warty-release-install-i386.iso) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/warty/warty-release-install-amd64.iso)  │    Not  Available    │    Not  Available    ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃       Ubuntu 4.10 Live      │       [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/warty/warty-release-live-i386.iso)       │    Not  Available    │    Not  Available    ┃
┗━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┷━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┷━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┷━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┛

┏━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┯━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┯━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┯━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┓
┃     Version of Ubuntu (Server)     │     Directly    │      Torrent      │     Metalink     ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃           Ubuntu 14.04 LTS          │   [32-bit](http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04/ubuntu-14.04-server-i386.iso) or [64-bit](http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04/ubuntu-14.04-server-amd64.iso)  │   [32-bit](http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04/ubuntu-14.04-server-i386.iso.torrent) or [64-bit](http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04/ubuntu-14.04-server-amd64.iso.torrent)  │   [32-bit](http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04/ubuntu-14.04-server-i386.manifest) or [64-bit](http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04/ubuntu-14.04-server-amd64.metalink)  ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃       Ubuntu 13.10       │   [32-bit](http://releases.ubuntu.com/13.10/ubuntu-13.10-server-i386.iso) or [64-bit](http://releases.ubuntu.com/13.10/ubuntu-13.10-server-amd64.iso)  │   [32-bit](http://releases.ubuntu.com/13.10/ubuntu-13.10-server-i386.iso.torrent) or [64-bit](http://releases.ubuntu.com/13.10/ubuntu-13.10-server-amd64.iso.torrent)  │   [32-bit](http://releases.ubuntu.com/13.10/ubuntu-13.10-server-i386.metalink) or [64-bit](http://releases.ubuntu.com/13.10/ubuntu-13.10-server-amd64.metalink)  ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃       Ubuntu 13.04       │   [32-bit](http://releases.ubuntu.com/13.04/ubuntu-13.04-server-i386.iso) or [64-bit](http://releases.ubuntu.com/13.04/ubuntu-13.04-server-amd64.iso)  │   [32-bit](http://releases.ubuntu.com/13.04/ubuntu-13.04-server-i386.iso.torrent) or [64-bit](http://releases.ubuntu.com/13.04/ubuntu-13.04-server-i386.iso.torrent)  │   [32-bit](http://releases.ubuntu.com/13.04/ubuntu-13.04-server-i386.metalink) or [64-bit](http://releases.ubuntu.com/13.04/ubuntu-13.04-server-amd64.metalink)  ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃       Ubuntu 12.10       │   [32-bit](http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.10/ubuntu-12.10-server-i386.iso) or [64-bit](http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.10/ubuntu-12.10-server-amd64.iso)  │   [32-bit](http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.10/ubuntu-12.10-server-i386.iso.torrent) or [64-bit](http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.10/ubuntu-12.10-server-amd64.iso.torrent)  │   [32-bit](http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.10/ubuntu-12.10-server-i386.metalink) or [64-bit](http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.10/ubuntu-12.10-server-amd64.metalink)  ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃           Ubuntu 12.04 LTS          │   [32-bit](http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.04/ubuntu-12.04.4-server-i386.iso) or [64-bit](http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.04/ubuntu-12.04.4-server-amd64.iso)  │   [32-bit](http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.04/ubuntu-12.04.4-server-i386.iso.torrent) or [64-bit](http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.04/ubuntu-12.04.4-server-amd64.iso.torrent)  │   [32-bit](http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.04/ubuntu-12.04.4-server-i386.metalink) or [64-bit](http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.04/ubuntu-12.04.4-server-amd64.metalink)  ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃       Ubuntu 11.10       │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/oneiric/ubuntu-11.10-server-i386.iso) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/oneiric/ubuntu-11.10-alternate-amd64.iso)  │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/oneiric/ubuntu-11.10-server-i386.iso.torrent) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/oneiric/ubuntu-11.10-server-amd64.iso.torrent)  │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/oneiric/ubuntu-11.10-server-i386.metalink) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/oneiric/ubuntu-11.10-server-amd64.metalink)  ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃       Ubuntu 11.04       │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/11.04/ubuntu-11.04-server-i386.iso) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/11.04/ubuntu-11.04-server-amd64.iso)  │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/11.04/ubuntu-11.04-server-i386.iso.torrent) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/11.04/ubuntu-11.04-server-amd64.iso.torrent)  │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/11.04/ubuntu-11.04-server-i386.metalink) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/11.04/ubuntu-11.04-server-amd64.metalink)  ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃       Ubuntu 10.10       │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/10.10/ubuntu-10.10-server-i386.iso) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/10.10/ubuntu-10.10-server-amd64.iso)  │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/10.10/ubuntu-10.10-server-i386.iso.torrent) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/10.10/ubuntu-10.10-server-amd64.iso.torrent)  │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/10.10/ubuntu-10.10-server-i386.metalink) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/10.10/ubuntu-10.10-server-amd64.metalink)  ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃           Ubuntu 10.04 LTS          │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/lucid/ubuntu-10.04.4-server-i386.iso) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/lucid/ubuntu-10.04.4-server-amd64.iso)  │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/lucid/ubuntu-10.04.4-server-i386.iso.torrent) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/lucid/ubuntu-10.04.4-server-amd64.iso.torrent)  │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/lucid/ubuntu-10.04.4-server-amd64.metalink) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/lucid/ubuntu-10.04.4-alternate-amd64.metalink)  ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃         Ubuntu 9.10         │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/karmic/ubuntu-9.10-server-i386.iso) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/karmic/ubuntu-9.10-server-amd64.iso)  │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/karmic/ubuntu-9.10-server-i386.iso.torrent) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/karmic/ubuntu-9.10-server-amd64.iso.torrent)  │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/karmic/ubuntu-9.10-server-amd64.metalink) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/karmic/ubuntu-9.10-server-i386.metalink)  ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃         Ubuntu 9.04         │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/jaunty/ubuntu-9.04-server-i386.iso) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/jaunty/ubuntu-9.04-server-amd64.iso)  │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/jaunty/ubuntu-9.04-server-i386.iso.torrent) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/jaunty/ubuntu-9.04-server-amd64.iso.torrent)  │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/jaunty/ubuntu-9.04-server-i386.metalink) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/jaunty/ubuntu-9.04-server-amd64.metalink)  ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃         Ubuntu 8.10         │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/intrepid/ubuntu-8.10-server-i386.iso) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/intrepid/ubuntu-8.10-server-amd64.iso)  │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/intrepid/ubuntu-8.10-server-i386.iso.torrent) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/intrepid/ubuntu-8.10-server-amd64.iso.torrent)  │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/intrepid/ubuntu-8.10-server-i386.metalink) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/intrepid/ubuntu-8.10-server-amd64.metalink)  ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃        Ubuntu 8.04 LTS       │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/hardy/ubuntu-8.04.4-server-i386.iso) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/hardy/ubuntu-8.04.4-server-amd64.iso)  │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/hardy/ubuntu-8.04.4-server-i386.iso.torrent) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/hardy/ubuntu-8.04.4-server-amd64.iso.torrent)  │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/hardy/ubuntu-8.04.4-server-i386.metalink) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/hardy/ubuntu-8.04.4-server-amd64.metalink)  ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃         Ubuntu 7.10         │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/gutsy/ubuntu-7.10-server-i386.iso) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/gutsy/ubuntu-7.10-server-amd64.iso)  │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/gutsy/ubuntu-7.10-server-i386.iso.torrent) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/gutsy/ubuntu-7.10-server-amd64.iso.torrent)  │    Not  Available    ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃         Ubuntu 7.04         │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/feisty/ubuntu-7.04-server-i386.iso) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/feisty/ubuntu-7.04-server-amd64.iso)  │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/feisty/ubuntu-7.04-server-i386.iso.torrent) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/feisty/ubuntu-7.04-server-amd64.iso.torrent)  │    Not  Available    ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃         Ubuntu 6.10         │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/edgy/ubuntu-6.10-server-i386.iso) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/edgy/ubuntu-6.10-server-amd64.iso)  │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/edgy/ubuntu-6.10-server-i386.iso.torrent) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/edgy/ubuntu-6.10-server-amd64.iso.torrent)  │    Not  Available    ┃
┠──────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┨
┃        Ubuntu 6.06 LTS       │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/dapper/ubuntu-6.06.1-server-i386.iso) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/dapper/ubuntu-6.06.1-server-amd64.iso)  │   [32-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/dapper/ubuntu-6.06.1-server-i386.iso.torrent) or [64-bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/dapper/ubuntu-6.06.1-server-amd64.iso.torrent)  │    Not  Available    ┃
┗━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┷━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┷━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┷━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┛

Comment: Note that these are only the official releases, there may be unofficial releases also like PowerPc(PPC) versions or similar.

Answer (score 1):

## Download it right now

**DESKTOP**

32 Bit       [iso](http://releases.ubuntu.com/precise/ubuntu-12.04-desktop-i386.iso)  -[torrent](http://releases.ubuntu.com/precise/ubuntu-12.04-desktop-i386.iso.torrent)

64 Bit         [iso](http://releases.ubuntu.com/precise/ubuntu-12.04-desktop-amd64.iso)  -[torrent](http://releases.ubuntu.com/precise/ubuntu-12.04-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent)

**SERVER**

32 Bit      [iso](http://releases.ubuntu.com/precise/ubuntu-12.04-server-i386.iso)  [torrent](http://releases.ubuntu.com/precise/ubuntu-12.04-server-i386.iso.torrent)

64 Bit      [iso](http://releases.ubuntu.com/precise/ubuntu-12.04-server-amd64.iso)   [torrent](http://releases.ubuntu.com/precise/ubuntu-12.04-server-amd64.iso.torrent)

[**wubi**](http://releases.ubuntu.com/precise/wubi.exe)

Installation instruction Instructions [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/install-ubuntu-desktop)

Answer (score 0):

http://www.ubuntu.com/download is the link to go for downloading latest ubuntu version. If it is not there here, probably not released yet.
That link would not change, at least as long as humanity survives.

Answer (score -1):

You can directly upgrade from terminal using:

```
do-release-upgrade
```