# Downloading a Boot Disc

Tags: installation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where can I download Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125264/where-can-i-download-ubuntu)

Where can I download a copy of ubuntu to burn as a boot disc i can install from after formatting the HD>

All i can find is the wubi file, which is from within windows. Also it has no iso file to burn to dvd.

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to [the official Ubuntu download page](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) and click on **Get
   Ubuntu 12.10**.
2. You will be taken to the donate funds page. Scroll down to the
   bottom and click on **Not now, take me to the download**.
3. The iso file will start downloading or you will see a prompt to save
   the file.

If you want the 64 bit version then in the [first page](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) You can *Choose your flavor*. There is also a separate button for the older and long term support version 12.04 LTS on the same page.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

ON the Ubuntu website, click on downloads, click if you want 12.10 or 12.04, 64 bit or 32 bit, and then the download will begin.

Comment: Including the URL link will improve this answer.

Comment: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop

Comment: that's the download i'm referring to. There is no iso to burn as a bootable disc, and wubi is the file to run from in windows. i don't want to do that.

Comment: You need to get a program to burn it to a boot disk and then boot to that disk.

Comment: i have Nero for burning dvd's, but the file doesn't contain an iso file or something like that to create a disc.

Comment: did it download as an iso file?

Comment: it downloads as a rar file and i can't see an iso file inside.

Comment: What OS is this on?

Comment: I run XP. Why on earth is this so awkward? Surely it should be the easiest thing in the world to provide: a file i can burn to dvd to run as a bootable disc to install after formatting the drive?

Comment: so apparently its as easy as right clicking it and renaming it into an iso file as it says here:

Comment: http://www.pronetworks.org/forums/how-to-convert-a-rar-file-into-an-iso-file-t51902.html

Comment: the file won't let me write to dvd, it says cd only!?!

Answer (score 0):

Going by the comments in the answers posted before in this thread, if I understand your problem, then, just copy all the files to a CD/DVD using Nero or other good software that you have, the CD/DVD should have at least about 750 MB free space and then restart your computer, and follow the procedure given [here](https://www.help.ubuntu.com/community/BootFromCD).
Hope this helps, post if you have any trouble.

Comment: I can't burn the file to DVD, only CD. Why not DVD? Also I need the proper install file, not Wubi because I don't want to install inside windows.

Comment: I didn't understand why can't you burn to a DVD. Please explain what happens when you burn to a DVD. And yes, after burning the DVD/CD and verifying that all files have been copied to it, restart your computer and follow the procedure given in the link posted, you can install it alongside Windows.

Comment: it tells me that it can't burn it on dvd, that it needs a cd, as i said. also i need the CORRECT file. this is wubi. i need the file i can boot as a fresh install from a FORMATTED DRIVE. as i've said