# Download of ubuntu Failed

Tags: downloads

My download of ubuntu 14.04.2 desktop failed. I've tried everything. I paid for it and it started but failed. How do I restart it?

I've tried everything but I can't send this post.

Comment: Please be specific: Download from ubuntu.com or installation or maybe you have installed it but it's not starting...

Comment: Also please specify what you mean by "I paid for it." You paid whom?

Comment: Try and follow the instructions in http://askubuntu.com/questions/125264/where-can-i-download-the-latest-release-of-ubuntu to download and http://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu to install it.

Comment: "I paid for it" Then you got ripped off... Ubuntu is and always will be free.

Comment: Exactly how it fails? Are you using `wget`? What's the error message you get?

Answer (score 0):

do you want to install just ubuntu or do you want to dual boot linux and windows? to just install ubuntu, you have to burn the image to a cd or use unetbootin to copy it to a flash drive and boot it up and follow the instructions to install it